# Why are these Facebook URL share and like counts different on the API vs Widget?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

Like widget gives 35k for http://www.boredpanda.com

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php?action=like&channel=&container_width=96&href=http:%2f%2fwww.boredpanda.com%2f&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&share=false&show_faces=false&width=140
```

Share widget gives 35k for http://www.boredpanda.com

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/share_button.php?container_width=613&href=http%3A%2F%2Fboredpanda.com&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&mobile_iframe=true&sdk=joey
```

API URL gives 35K shares and 257 likes if I understand it correctly

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&id=http://www.boredpanda.com
```

Can someone explain why the shares and likes widgets give the same stats? And am I correct in reading that JSON that it has 257 likes?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_233117017073109